# Add iOS widgets to the macOS target

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, macos-big-sur, widgetkit

I have a SwiftUI App with widgets all works fine in the catalyst version or compiling the widgets directly for macOS, but when I add it to the macOS target (not catalyst) I get the following error

`/Users/franciscomisaellanderoychante/proyects/Revisits/Revisits.xcodeproj Building for macOS, but the embedded app extension 'revisitsWidgetExtension.appex' is building for iOS. You may need to configure 'revisitsWidgetExtension.appex' to build for macOS.`

[image: widgets]

But like you can see the widgets are actually target for macOS too

in the macOS I have this selected

[image]

What im trying to do is to use the existing widget with the macOS app

any idea of what is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found the solution you have to add a new widget extension target to macOS (The iOS widget only works on Catalyst)

[image]

Once you do that you can use the same configuration and files that you used on the iOS extension just add the new widget to the target and done.

Comment: Do you also use configurable widget options? Somehow it works on iOS but not on macOS. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74321672/widget-configuration-not-working-on-macos)