# Widget configuration not working on macOS

Tags: swift, xcode, widget

I made a widget for my iOS app. It works fine. Now I'm porting it to my macOS app, but somehow the widget configuration is not working. The items are shown but I'm not able to select them somehow.

[image]

See a screenshot, but please take a look at the video I made: https://youtu.be/6FtBvFQV_1k showing the problem.

Has anyone any clue what's going wrong here?

Comment: I’ve contacted Apple. The say it’s a bug in macos.

Comment: I've this problem too. 

For Static Configuration, The behavior will be like what you describe in the post. 

For Dynamic Configuration, It works as expected. No problem like in Static Configuration.

Comment: Apparently the next macos version will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In macOS Venture 13.2 the issue is solved by Apple ;)